Serving the customers vs serve the customers
Speaker 1: What do you want to do?
Speaker 2: "Serving the customers/serve the customers"
What is the appropriate answer to this question?

"[I want to] serve the customers."

Serve the customers=shortened form and fine.

Both 'serving the customers' and 'serve the customers' aren't great answers.
As the question asks what you want to do, a possible straightforward answer in complete sentence is

I want to serve the customers.

as what Kate said.
I use want to as wanna is informal.
Edit
Serve the customers, a fragment, is possible in an informal context.

But in an informal context people often reply with a sentence fragment, which is why I put I want to in square brackets - to imply that it can be omitted.
